# Is mapping via msg.sender as secure as calling a function only by the owner?

Tags: solidity, mapping

On my implementation, only the owner of the contract's function was able to call some important functions that I defined. I changed the implementation as by removing `onlyOwner`, and adding `cluster_constract[msg.sender].deleteAll()` that will allow only the message sender to call that important function, if their address mapped to a list. `cluster_constract[<my_address>] = list`.

[Q] If an attacker knows the address of the msg.sender, can he calls `deleteAll()` function (`cluster_constract["<valid_address>"].deleteAll();` ) from an external contract? Is my approach safe to use?

```
contract owned { 
  address  public owner;
  function owned() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
  function ownerOnly() {
    if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
  }
  modifier onlyOwner {
    if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
       _
  }
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
    owner = newOwner;
  }
}
```

**Before:**

```
  LinkedList.data list;
  function deleteAll() onlyOwner {      
     list.deleteAll();
  }
```

**After:**

```
  mapping(address => LinkedList.data) cluster_constract;

  function add_cluster() {
     cluster_constract[msg.sender] = list;
  }

  function deleteAll() { //if cluster_constract[msg.sender] exits deleteAll() can be called.
     cluster_constract[msg.sender].deleteAll();        
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `msg.sender` is secure as elliptic curve cryptography.  Ethereum uses the same curve and key size as Bitcoin.  Everyone knows `msg.sender` but only possession of the private key will allow someone to sign a transaction as that `msg.sender`.

A transaction actually doesn't contain a sender.  The address of the sender is derived from the signature on the transaction.

If you look at token contracts, you'll see they usually use a mapping of balances where the key is `msg.sender`.

As @Edmund wrote, it's simpler and more secure, whereas a modifier like `onlyOwner` needs to be explicitly attached to all functions that need to be locked down.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if anything it's probably more secure to enforce ownership by keeping it under a mapping key, because you can't write code to change it without considering who it belongs to, whereas if you're relying on explicit ownership checks you may forget to apply them.